# what is the difference and uses of these lines of code?

Tags: python

first line of code:

```
for i in list:
   print(i)
```

second line of code:

```
print(i for i in list)
```

what would I use each of them for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see for yourself what the difference is.
The first one iterates over `range` and then prints integers.

```
>>> for i in range(4):
...     print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
```

The second one is a generator expression.

```
>>> print(i for i in range(4))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10b6c20f0>
```

How iteration works in the generator. Python generators are a simple way of creating iterators.

Simply speaking, a generator is a function that returns an object (iterator) which we can iterate over (one value at a time).

```
>>> g=(i for i in range(4))
>>> print(g)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x100f015d0>
>>> print(next(g))
0
>>>
>>> print(next(g))
1
>>> print(next(g))
2
>>> print(next(g))
3
>>> print(next(g))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration


>>> g=(i for i in range(4))
>>> for i in g:
...     print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
>>> for i in g:
...     print(i)
...
>>>
>>>
```

In python3, you can use tuple unpacking to print the generator. If that's what you were going for.

```
>>> print(*(i for i in range(4)))
0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet will iterate over your list and print the value of i for each pass through the loop.  In most cases you will want to use something like this to print the values in a list:

```
my_list = list(range(5))
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The second snippet will evaluate the expression in the print statement and print the result.  Since the expression in print statement, `i for i in my_list` evaluates to a generator expression, that string representation of that generator expression will be outputted.  I cannot think of any real world cases where that is the result you would want.

```
my_list = list(range(5))
print(i for i in my_list)
```

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E9EB2F0>
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the (since edited) answers that suggested otherwise:

1. the second one is NOT a list comprehension.
2. the two code snippets do NOT do the same thing.

```py
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print(i for i in x)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000002322FA1BA50>
```

The second one is printing a generator object because `(i for i in x)` is a generator. The first snippet simply prints the elements in the list one at a time.

BTW: don't use `list` as a variable name. It's the name of a built-in type in Python, so when you use it as a variable name, you overwrite the constructor for that type. Basically, you're erasing the built-in `list()` function.

Comment: didn't mean to use list as a variable but to just say "some list"... should have put that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is just a loop going through a list and printing the elements one by one:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

The second way, `list comprehension`, creates an iterable you can store (list, dictionary, etc.)

```
l = [i for i in l]
print( l ) #[1, 2, 3]
print( l[0] ) #1
print( l[1:] ) #[2, 3]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
1
[2, 3]
```

The second is used for doing 1 thing to all the elements e.g. turn all elements from string to int:

```
l = ['1', '2', '3']
l = [int(i) for i in l] #now the list is [1, 2, 3]
```

loops are better for doing a lot of things:

```
for i in range(4):
    #Code
    #more code
    #lots of more code
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

The second one is a generator expression. Both will give same result if you convert the generator expression to list comprehension. In short, list comprehensions are used to increase both memory and execution efficiency. However, they are generally applicable to small blocks of codes, generally one to two lines.

For more information, see this link on official python website - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehensions